# Xamarin hardware setup

Tags: windows, macos, installation, xamarin, hardware

My company just decided to do App development in house for iOs,Android and Windows and decided to use Xamarin.

We am not sure what hardware to get? Do I need Mac for development if I have a Mac build server. Does anyone have recommended hardware setup?

//Jón

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Visual Studio on a PC or Xamarin Studio on a Mac.  Using VS requires a Xamarin Business (or better) license.  For iOS development with VS you MUST also have a Mac setup as a build server.  Android and Windows phone development can be done entirely on a PC.

For specific hardware requirements, the usual rules apply - the more RAM and faster disk/SSD you have, the happier you will be.

Comment: Ok, What I am looking for is that if you are developing for iOs, Android and Windows would you recommend a Mac rather than Windows for development. Even if I have a build server for all platforms.

Comment: I personally use a MBP with XS for iOS and Android dev, and run a Windows VM for Windows Phone development.  But you could also use a Windows machine with VS and a Mac build host for iOS.  It's mostly personal preference and convenience.

Comment: Like Jason said it is all personal preference but some mitigating factors may be, is your source control TFS? Are you a .NET shop with a bunch of VS licenses already? If so PC may be the right way to go.